# Error: $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors when doing batch prediction in R

Tags: r, linux, keras, model

I train the CNN model using kera library in linux R.
Then I use `predict_on_batch(model,Xtrain)`.
However, I got `Error $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`.
Xtrain is an array with 4 dimension and it is atomic vector.

I can did batch prediction in my local window OS and I got no issue.
May I know how can I solve the `Error $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`?

Thank you.

Comment: `predict_on_batch(model, as.data.frame(Xtrain))` maybe? That error relates to trying to subset like `object$part` on a non-`list` or `data.frame` object.

Comment: Are the `keras` (and R) versions the same on your local Windows OS and your Linux R?